# lower current than expected through simple circuit powering laser diode

Tags: transistors, laser-diode

I have a circuit I designed for a raspberry pi to turn a laser off and on. I designed it to supply approx 22mA but it's barely getting 11mA. I've tried numerous tests but I can't figure out what's wrong

Circuit:
[image]

Vcc = 5V, GPIO BCM 21 = 3.3V, voltage loss across laser (L1.V) = 4V

For that circuit, I tried to get R2 with the eq 
$$Vcc−I2R2−L1.V−Q1.V_{CE}=0 \\
R2 = \frac{1}{22mA} (5V - 0.02V (negligible) - 4V)$$
which gave me $$R2 \approx 49\Omega$$

Using that, I've tested these values
$$
\begin{align}
I_{R2} &\approx 10.8mA (!) \\
I_{R1} &\approx 1.8mA \\
L1.V &\approx 4.6V \\
Q1.V_{CE} &\approx 0.02V \\
\end{align}
$$

**edit** updated L1.V from 4 to 4.6
**update** the laser isn't just a simple diode, it has integrated APC

Datasheets
[2n4401 npn bjt](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/661741.pdf)
[syd1230 laser](http://www.seeedstudio.com/document/HLM1230.pdf) (link is to HML1230 docs because SYD1230 docs do not appear to exist and laser closer resembles HML1230 in appearance, ie. has focusable 
 acrylic lens)

I've looked over all the data sheets (the whopping 2 of them), rechecked calcs, design... I can't figure out what I didn't account for. Why isn't \$I_{R2}\$ closer to the expected 22mA

Comment: Whats the actual voltage across the laser and the resistor and the transistor when you turn it on? Are those your calculated values or measured? Also across R1? Did you measure the resistors or just used the color value?

Comment: Can you link to laser datasheet? 4V seems like an odd value for a bare diode

Comment: Posted the datasheet for the laser. The total voltage is 4.99V, I made a recording mistake on `L1.V` originally. R1 was read from the resistor, R2 was measured

Comment: Note this is not a bare diode: "Built In APC Driver", you can replace your resistor with a diode to drop 5V to ~4.4V for Vin spec of diode module

Comment: Thanks, I included that in the post. I'll test the diode solution tomorrow

Comment: 0.4 / 49 = 8 mA closer to your actual current.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused by that, could you expand? @Passerby

Comment: Meaning Since your laser is using a higher voltage than you calculated, there is a lower voltage drop across your resistor, which means a lower current through it. So assuming 0.4V, that's only 8 milliamps which is closer to the 10 you are seeing.

Comment: It seems that the APC part of the laser raises it's voltage loss if you decrease R2. I tried dropping it to 30ohm and there was no change in current

Comment: APC = Automatic Power Control, its a current source with optical feedback, if its a good module the current should be the same at any allowable supply voltage

Comment: @Alter, the APC function means this laser has its own internal current limiting. R2 will not function as a current-setting resistor, it will just mess up the internal driver circuit of the laser module. As others said, get rid of R2 and replace it with one or two diodes.

Comment: Also, the datasheet you linked under the text "SYD1230 laser" actually goes to a part number HLM1230. -1 for making things more difficult than they should be.

Comment: The adafruit page for SYD1230 (not HLM1230) gives an input voltage range 2.8 to 5.2 V, in which case you don't even need a voltage dropping diode. Just get rid of R2 and you're done.

Comment: I'm rather confused about the HLM1230 vs SYD1230 myself. The part says SYD1230 but looks more like HLM1230; when searching for SYD1230 docs the HLM1230 docs come up. I haven't found much in the way of docs for SYD1230 at all (just the adafruit page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the power supply from which you power the LASER branch? Summing all the voltage drops in that branch gives 
0.02V + 4V + 12mA × 49Ω = 4.6V, which are not the 5V you should have.

It seems that your power supply cannot handle so much current and is dropping out.

Check that your power source for that branch is not overloaded by other loads in your circuit, since 12mA seems a bit too low to overload a power supply, even small on-board regulators.

**EDIT**

After you corrected your question and added the LASER's datasheet it becomes apparent that you are outside of that LASER's specs. Just for a tiny 0.1V, now, but you could have damaged your laser during power-up when the whole 5V could have been fed to the LASER module.

That module expects 4V *constant voltage* supply (±0.5V max). Connect the module to a bench power supply set at exactly 4V and try if it's still working. If it is, then follow the advice in a comment of @sstobbe: get rid of R2 and put a diode in series with the module.

For extra safety, since at low currents diodes have a smaller voltage drop and so a 0.7V drop cannot be guaranteed (e.g., it could be 0.56V, depending on the diode actual model), it would be better to *put **two diodes** in series*, at least initially, just to be sure you work on the lower side of the specs.

After you *measure the actual voltage drop across those diodes* you might remove one and see if it works still in specs (but if it works with two diodes, maybe it's better to leave it that way, just in case your power rail has a small hiccup).

Comment: you caught a mistake I made, apparently I recorded the voltage for the wrong test (I tested R2 = 97 Ohms before the one I posted). I checked the power supply and get 4.99V, with roughly 4.5-4.6V loss over the laser and 10.8mA